# Matlab/Octav, minimising rounding error during computation

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, rounding-error

My question regards best practices to minimise rounding errors in computer calculations.

In my Numerical Methods course I have been taught that the size of memory (presumably RAM) Matlab uses during computation is significantly larger than the size of storage memory used for storing variables. When dealing with division of long expressions we are encouraged to divide them up in nominator and denominator variables for readability.
Does this mean that between thes two
$$V=f(x)/g(x);$$ and $$ W=f(x), Z=g(x);$$$$ Y=W/Z $$
$Y$ has more of a rounding error because it uses storage while $V$ only uses RAM memory during computation?

Comment: Maybe, but there are so many more important causes of numerical inaccuracy... the first one being when denominator $g(x)$ is many order of magnitudes less than $f(x)$...

Comment: Did you try the calculations? Do you see any difference between V and Y?

Comment: And in almost all cases “storage” means RAM, so your last sentence doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: What is the memory used in computation vs stored variables called?

Comment: This remark is probably about the 80 bit "extended double" FPU x87 registers and the storage in normal 64bit double. This is no concern nowadays as floating point operations are done in 64 bit with other parts of the CPU like SSE. To get reliable 80 bit operations one would need direct assembly code. A compiler could transform the order of operations and storage of intermediate variables in different ways, which is more likely to prevent reproducible results. In script languages like Matlab all visible operations will be reproducible 64bit. There will be no difference in the given example.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for the extensive answer. It seems I have a new interesting rabbit hole to explore.